# How to ask manager to split payment for upcoming training I want to attend

Tags: communication, manager, training

I am a technical team lead on the information security team where I work. Our team and company encourages employees to pursue training and employees have a wide choice in how they want to pursue professional development.

I found [this training event](https://www.isaca.org/training-and-events/in-person-training/training-weeks/cyber-security-essentials/cyber-security-essentials-may) hosted by a professional cybersecurity organization of ISACA that fits well with what I currently do, cybersecurity operations and advisory. Even though I am an ISACA member, it will still cost approximately 1000 dollars to attend. Our company has a training budget that can cover this, however, I also have 5 team members who also want to attend other trainings and virtual conferences. The price tag for 6 of us will exceed our team's training budget by a significant amount. Our budget for this year is already approved so asking for more money is not an option. I am the most senior member on the team, so in a sense junior members may benefit from more training than myself.

I am willing to cover partial cost out of my pocket and only use partial company training budget to maximize opportunity for all team members to attend training. I have great standing in the team and company and am highly respected.

How do I approach my manager to see if split payment is possible?

Comment: Is it 1000 per member or 1000 for everyone? And is the training budget for everyone or individuals? If it is individuals, why wouldn't the budget cover it for everyone? Personally I would not pay for it.

Comment: It is per member

Comment: We dont have sufficient money and dont want team members to miss out due to something they cannot control. As I said, they may benefit more than I as I am senior and they are junior members.

Comment: _"I am willing to cover partial cost out of pocket and only use partial company training budget to maximize opportunity for all team members to attend training."_ Can you clarify if you would pay for the overall difference or it would be split up among the other attendees as well?

Comment: If you do wish to pay for part of it yourself, see if it is tax deductible, or see if it can be taken out of your pay.

Comment: Also, looking at that course, a cancellation fee, and wholly non-refundable after a certain date, is amusing to me. It's a zoom call. Lots of pockets to line in the InfoSec world.

Comment: Whatever you do, do not pay for anything yourself.  It's completely unprofessional and unbusinesslike - and will lead to YOU being treated in an unprofessional and unbusinesslike manner.

Comment: excellent point from @GregoryCurrie that it is a "thousand dollar zoom call" ...

Comment: @Gregory , while this is a expensive training, our team is looked upon by our company senior management (CISO level), as trusted advisors for cyber risk. I already have 2 certifications , CISA and CISSP so I want to build up the team and these trainings are something they asked me if they can attend. I think it's a wise investment

Comment: If not for Covid, the North American ISACA Conference and the GRC conferences in August that my team mates want to attend  would have been in person, with amenities covered.

Comment: Is it possible that if you do pay the split cost, that the $ amount you pay can be recuperated via another, non-training budget mechanism?  EG Extra paid leave?

Comment: @Anthony If your company's senior management hold your team in such high regard as you've mentioned, then they absolutely should cover the full cost. The company makes the investment, not employees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"How do I approach my manager to see if split payment is possible?"*

I was in a **similar situation** for a quite expensive training course regarding OTP's - we ended up in **splitting the costs** since **budget was already carved in stone**. I don't think it's unprofessional as @Fattie stated in his answer since, in regards to mentioned circumstances, it was **still a win-win situation** for me and the company.

I would simply **contact your manager in writing** stating the importance and the **possible benefits of the training** for the company and the team as well as mention that **you are aware** of the fact that the yearly consolidated budget would be exceeded by X-amount of $ if all of your team-members will attend.

In the next paragraph I would ask him if **they would accept** that the difference would be **payed by the individuals** attending the mentioned training and if they are keen that all members of the team would attend and the dates of the training **wont interfere with any important schedules** (Keep in mind that they might need some or all members in case of an emergency, important meeting, deadline, milestone that week).

Something along the lines of:

> Hey [enter name here]! Our team recently found out that there's a really useful training event named [enter name here] held at [enter location and date-range]. Our company and the team would really benefit from this training-event because [enter plausable reasons here].
>
> I am aware that the yearly budget for our team is exceeded by [enter $-delta here] since the sign-up fee is around [enterx-amount of $ here] for each person attending. Would it be possible that the difference is payed by each individual that would like to attend?
>
> Also, would the date [enter date-range here] interfere with any important, upcoming schedules, meetings or milestones/deadlines?
>
> Best, [enter your name here]

**Note:** Make sure all of your **team members are on-board with the idea** and are also **willing to attend and pay-up** for the difference. Also keep the option in mind that if someone doesn't want to attend, they might be **willing to pass their share** of the yearly training budget **to the other members** to reduce the difference for them.

Another option would be (as mentioned by the others) to ask your manager to talk to their superiors, notifiying them that a temporary budget increase this year in order to meet the amount needed would be beneficial to the company for certain reaons.

Comment: This only works if the cost of the other 5 trainings does not exceed the budget.  Asking other employees to cover their own training is a big ask.  Offering to do it yourself is something else entirely.

Comment: @Donald I'm not 100% sure if the OP is willing to pay up for the overall difference, maybe the OP can clarify. But thats why I wrote the last paragraph..

Answer (score 3):

> I am willing to cover partial cost out of my pocket

I would **set that idea aside**.

To put it as simply as possible: it's just not professional.

You don't "pay for things yourself" as a professional. Do everything in a business-like manner.

> How do I approach my manager to see if split payment is possible?

Simply *discuss* the issue with the manager. Don't present it as "something you want".

Comment: How is this "not professional"? The OP wants to attend an event and is interested so much that they are willing to partially pay for this so that it's not unfair to the colleagues. Getting the company to pay for the event even if it means OP's colleagues will not be able to attend trainings of their own, now that would be unprofessional or at the very least selfish.

Comment: Companies partially covering expenses (especially up to some budget or limit) is not particularly uncommon in my experience. In fact, I would probably expect that from pretty much *every* company if you, say, start overspending on a business trip. Although I would agree that you should just start with a discussion.

Comment: Covering "the gap" in costs could be seen as setting a precedent for further training sessions, where they start to expect some/senior/specific members to pay part of their own training costs. Not only is that unrealistic in many cases, but it also gives people the idea that the training budget can shrink, instead of grow. It also starts the slide towards "employees pay for all their own training" in a toxic environment. It's safer for the employee(s) to start a conversation with the manager, as suggested, about growing the budget, rather than offering cash up front.

Comment: Take a million +points and give them to @computercarguy

Comment: @computercarguy If "People care enough about training to pay for it themselves" leads to "Just let them pay for their own training" instead of "Maybe we should pay for more of it to make them happier", then that's indeed quite a toxic environment where employees aren't valued at all. Nowhere I'd want to work.

Comment: @JohnEye certainly, no worker should ever pay one cent for anything to a company.  Any company that takes a cent from a worker is evil, and a worker giving them a cent is enabling.  Give them a cent and they will take a mile of your life.

Comment: @Fattie I understand the sentiment, but the training benefits not only the company, but also the employee by making them more valuable on the job market. That being said, I'd never offer to pay a part of training that is beneficial only for the company, but if I'm interested too, I don't have a problem with that. I've gone to a conference privately after it was paid for by the company the year before and I certainly didn't feel taken advantage of.

Comment: @NotThatGuy,the sad fact of the matter is that most of us already work for companies like that. Companies that expect you to do training and other education "on your own time" are forcing their employees to pay for their own training, especially the ones that expect you to take vaca or unpaid time off to go to industry conferences, seminars, etc., even when it's "just travel time". It's one thing to do this on your own because you like it, but a totally different thing when it's expected. Too many people don't realize they are in that trap, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider asking that your manager goes to his superiors to get the budget increased just for this year, perhaps using some of next years’ allocation.

I would not suggest that all should personally pay a portion as some may be in difficult financial conditions...

Comment: Good idea with the budget increase, but it doesn't seem to be an option: _"Our budget for this year is already approved so asking for more money is not an option."_